# Hydrogen Peroxide - Iron Nail Galvanic Cell?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions, electricity

I am planning to create a simple galvanic cell made up of common household materials.

Suppose I have hydrogen peroxide (to serve as cathode), diluted in water, in one beaker, and I have a bunch of iron nails (to serve as anode), also diluted in water, in another beaker. I put a graphite electrode (in the form of a pencil) in the $\ce{H2O2}$ solution to serve as an inert electrode. Then I'll have a U-tube containing $\ce{NaCl}$ to serve as a salt bridge between the two beakers. I will then connect the two electrodes using alligator clips into an LED. Computing from their reduction potentials, I am supposed to get $2.21~\mathrm{V}$ under standard conditions.

Will the set-up work? If so, do you think it is possible to connect many set-ups in series in order to produce $9$ Volts? I will appreciate all sorts of suggestions.

Comment: N.B. household hydrogen peroxide is ~3%, with ~97% water. Greater concentrations can be quite dangerous, while 3% solutions may not produce a noticeable difference in EMF from water.